# Error Log Analysis - Apache, Nginx

Tags: regex, apache, nginx, log-analysis

I want a Analyse from the Error Logs from Nginx & Apache. Only a count what is the most Error.
For Counting Access.logs i have found this script:

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}' /var/log/nginx/access.log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

But i can't regex and have zero Experience with awk.

Comment: can you please be specific about the problem ?

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: I want sort with counted number the error Logs. 
Like:
Count: Error
484: PHP Error: /Var/www/xyz.php
43: PHP Warning: /Var/www/asd.php